# Difference between init events in js file or html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

Is there a difference between lauch js functions from same JS file where they declared after page load, or in html template? When both signed into `$(document).ready(function () {...})`.

I assume that no, but I ran into a problem when replace my `ExampleService.init()` function from template to separate JS file. 
For example i have that construction:

**common.js**

```
var ExampleService= {
    catalogSpinner: '',

    init: function() {
      this.initEvents();
    },

    initEvents: function() {
      var self = this;

      $('.example-button').on('click', function() {
          //do some logic, append spinner...
          self.removeSpinner();
      });
    },

    removeSpinner: function() {
        $(this.catalogSpinner).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove().css({display: 'block'});
        });
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      ExampleService.catalogSpinner = '<div class="spinner"></div>'; // css3 animation

      ExampleService.init();
  });
</script>
```

That way all works perfect, my `catalogSpinner` overriden from template, and i can use them like DOM element.

---

*But!* if i move `ExampleService.init();` to `common.js` file, like that:

**common.js**

```
var ExampleService= {
    ...
    // all the same...
    ...
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    ExampleService.init();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     ExampleService.catalogSpinner = '<div class="spinner"></div>';     
  });
</script>
```

That way it wouldn't work. And throw console error `Uncaught TypeError: this.catalogSpinner.fadeOut is not a function`

Why it's happens? After all in both cases init functions starts only after full page load, and no matters that i override my variable after starting base functions. What im doing wrong?

---

About orders in which inits will executed. How i understand its no matter. Cause in any case, second document.ready from template file, always ovverride empty `catalogSpinner` variable from JS file, before click event happens

Comment: have you checked the order those events are called in? to me it looks like the call in common.js gets called before the index.html one.

Comment: First of all, you must have valid `jQuery` selector to use jQuery methods..

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a timing issue. What guarantee do you have that `$(document).ready` in common.js will fire after the same event handler in your html file (which is what needs to happen according to your implementation)?

Or, you need to make sure that when it occurs in common.js, that code can somehow retrieve the catalogSpinner value.

Also, catalogSpinner needs to be a valid jQuery object, not a string.

Comment: Yes, this could be the answer. But my event works on click, and while it will happen, second document.ready already override `catalogSpinner` variable, for correct value.
P.S Yeah, sorry type, i already have function which make them to correct jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

It will and it does work in both the cases. To use `jQuery` methods over DOM elements, you must have valid `jQuery` selectors which will return objects binded with `jQuery` methods.

Try this:

**case 1:**

*common.js*

```
var ExampleService= {
  catalogSpinner: '',

  init: function() {
    this.initEvents();
  },

  initEvents: function() {
    var self = this;

    $('.example-button').on('click', function() {
      //do some logic, append spinner...
      self.removeSpinner();
    });
  },

  removeSpinner: function() {
    this.catalogSpinner.fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove().css({display: 'block'});
    });
  }
};
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="common.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="spinner">Spinner</div>
<button type="button" class="example-button">Remove</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    ExampleService.catalogSpinner = $('.spinner');
    ExampleService.init();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**case 2:**

*common.js*

```
var ExampleService = {
  catalogSpinner: '',

  init: function () {
    this.initEvents();
  },

  initEvents: function () {
    var self = this;

    $('.example-button').on('click', function () {
      //do some logic, append spinner...
      self.removeSpinner();
    });
  },

  removeSpinner: function () {
    this.catalogSpinner.fadeOut('slow', function () {
      $(this).remove().css({display: 'block'});
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  'use strict';
  ExampleService.init();
});
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="common.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="spinner">Spinner</div>
<button type="button" class="example-button">Remove</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    ExampleService.catalogSpinner = $('.spinner');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that way not suitable for me. Also i can set catalogSpinner directly in JS file `catalogSpinner: '<div class="spinner"></div>',` and it will works. But I'm curious why described above example dont work. In any case second document.ready from template must override variable before  click event.

Comment: Yes, you can use `catalogSpinner: '<div class="spinner"></div>',` in JS too but while selecting it, you must use `$('.spinner')` as a selector. Try it this way.

Comment: But i dont want to have rendered element in my template, only directly set into variable. :( I understood that i can select them from template and use, but i don't want to do that, only directly set into variable.

Comment: Yes certainly you can do it that way but at the time of `ExampleService.catalogSpinner = $('.spinner');` that element should be there in the DOM and also note that `ExampleService.catalogSpinner = $('.spinner');` must be used to select that element not `ExampleService.catalogSpinner = '<div class="spinner"></div>';` and in you case where you do not want to have it in template, use `ExampleService.catalogSpinner = $('<div class="spinner"></div>');`